# Windows 7 64-bit can't display text after update

Tags: windows-7, windows

After my computer updated Windows, some programs can't display text labels.
You can see the error in this picture:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Try using a different font. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-windows-fonts

Comment: It seems windows is set to another language. (cant be positive about it yet) try changing language back to english. This usually only happens on windows 7 ultimate unless you chose to add some languages from windows update possibly? what verison windows 7 do you have? home, premium etc?

Comment: Some application like Outlook, Word, Excel ... still can't readable all text labels and menus

Comment: @TonyNgo - Verify the language packs that are installed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like windows is set to a different language. Change the default language and it should work fine.

You'd need to download a language pack, ideally from the Windows website. Here's a [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-language-packs-on-windows-nb/)

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: You'd need to download a language pack, ideally from the Windows website. Here's a [link](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-language-packs-on-windows-nb/)

Comment: Great! Now update your answer ;)

Comment: Updated just now.